# Toggle Class in if else statement-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to toggle a class in React (only in the else statement).

```
class Inf extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        pizzaData: data
    }
    }
    renderList(info){
      const list = this.state.pizzaData.map((entry, index) => {
              if (entry.occupied==true){
               return <li class="coloring" key={index}>Seat: {entry.seat}{entry.row}</li>;
             }
             else{
               return <li class="colored" key={index}>Seat: {entry.seat}{entry.row}</li>;
             }
           });
           return(
               <ul>{list}</ul>
           )
  }
```

Now, looking over some of the documentation I was unsure how to do this. I know that there needs to be a "toggle" on the li and (I think) something like this below the this.state={:

```
pizzaData:data
},
handleClick function(
```

But I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, you need a click handler. What is your goal, from a responsive standpoint? Do you want to click the `<li/>` and have it toggle itself?

Comment: Yes that's right. Basically if the user selects an li in the else statement it will change the corresponding li's color.

Comment: What does the data structure `pizzaData` look like?

Comment: It looks something like this: [
    {
        "seat": 20,
        "occupied": false
    },
    {
        "seat": 10,
        "occupied": true

    }

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple example of how you can update your code, also with two components (similar to the idea by @THEtheChad), but without using `context` since according to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#why-not-to-use-context) it is discouraged to use `context` directly if you want your app to be stable. If `state` and `props` management in app gets too complicated you can include `redux` (which internally also uses `context`), but for now I am not including `redux` since it be might over-complication in this simple case.

Here is `PizzaList` which has `pizzas` on its `state`. The component will render `PizzaItem` components and pass a callback down so that each `PizzaItem` can notify its parent (`PizzaList`) when it is clicked. `PizzaList` has the responsibility of toggling `PizzaItem` when it is clicked.

```
class PizzaList extends React.PureComponent {
    state = {
      pizzas: []
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      // fetch data about pizzas via an API and perform this.setState
      this.setState({ pizzas: [{ seat: 20, occupied: false }, { seat: 10, occupied: true }, { seat: 30, occupied: true }] });
    }
    handlePizzaItemClick = (pizzaInd) => {
      this.setState((prevState) => {

        // find clicked pizza and toggle its occupied property
         const pizzas = prevState.pizzas.map((pizza, ind) => {
            if (ind === pizzaInd)
               return { ...pizza, ...{ occupied: !pizza.occupied } };

            return pizza;
         });

        return { pizzas: pizzas };
      });
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <ul>
              {this.state.pizzas.map((pizza, index) => 
                <PizzaItem 
                  onClick={this.handlePizzaItemClick} 
                  index={index} 
                  pizza={pizza}
                />)}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

`PizzaItem` is a simple function component that doesn't have any state.

```
const PizzaItem = ({ index, pizza, onClick }) => {
    const { seat, row, occupied } = pizza;
    const pizzaClassName = occupied ? 'coloring' : 'colored';

    return (
      <li key={index} 
        className={pizzaClassName} 
        onClick={() => onClick(index)}> 
        Seat: {seat} {row}
      </li>
    );
}
```

Here is a working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4q036xpvn4).

Answer (score 0):

I would update your code and split it into two components, a list component and an item component (in this case pizza?). The list component would provide a method for modifying the list using the context API. In my example, I have an `updatePizza` method that I pass down in the context.

Then, in the child component, you have a click handler that updates the `occupied` status of the pizza and tells the parent what the new status is using the context method.

This makes sure that the parent component always has the current state for all the pizzas and passes that down to the children. The parent component becomes the single source of truth here.

```
class List extends React.Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    updatePizza: React.PropTypes.func
  }

  constructor({ pizzas }){
    super()
    this.state = { pizzas }
  }

  updatePizza = (idx, pizza) => {
    this.setState( ({ pizzas }) => {
      pizzas[idx] = pizza;
      return { pizzas }
    })
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return { updatePizza: this.updatePizza }
  }

  render(){
    return <ul>{this.state.pizzas.map((pizza, idx) => <Pizza key={ idx } { ...pizza }>)}<ul>
  }
}

class Pizza extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    updatePizza: React.PropTypes.func
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.state.occupied = !this.state.occupied;
    this.context.updatePizza(this.state.key, this.state)
  }

  render() {
    const { key, seat, row, occupied } = this.state;
    const status = occupied ? 'coloring' : 'colored';
    return <li key={ key } className={ status } onClick={ handleClick }> Seat: { seat } { row }</li>
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `context` something one should avoid using according to the React docs?
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Yes and no. It's still "experimental", meaning they're still refining it (and it's subject to change). That being said, all of the major libraries for React use it (redux, react-router, etc), so it's likely there won't be any breaking changes. If you're still afraid to touch it, your other option is to pass the bound method `updatePizza` to each child component as a property. The whole goal here is to do the mutation at the parent level and let the changes propagate. You can also use redux, then every component has access to the global state.